# shuffle dictionary values in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary and I want to shuffle the values, not the keys. For example:

```
{"a": "ACAT", "b": "ACTG", "c": "ACCC"}
```

and after shuffle:

```
{"a": "ACAT", "b": "ACTG", "c": "ACCC"}
```

but I don't know how I can do this work in python. I will be grateful if you help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `random` module has a function that shuffles in-place.

So we can get the dict's values, shuffle them, and construct a new dict.

Demo:

```
>>> import random
>>> d = {
...     "a": "ACAT",
...     "b": "ACTG",
...     "c": "ACCC"
... }
>>> shuffled = list(d.values())
>>> random.shuffle(shuffled)
>>> dict(zip(d, shuffled))
{'a': 'ACCC', 'b': 'ACTG', 'c': 'ACAT'}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do the same with a key? For example, suppose two people have the same dictionary and want to shuffle their dictionaries with one key and reach the same dictionaries. Is it possible?

Comment: @parisan I don't understand the question.

Comment: Suppose,I and you have the same dictionary, we are far apart but we want to shuffle dictionaries in such a way that they change the same way. Is there any way?

Comment: @parisan use the same random seed.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not give a different output each time?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `random.sample` to get a random ordered list of the dict's values, then map them with the keys in their default order. At the difference of using `shuffle` you can do this in once

```
from random import sample

result = dict(zip(values, sample(list(values.values()), len(values))))
```

Run that 10 times

```
{'a': 'ACAT', 'b': 'ACCC', 'c': 'ACTG'}
{'a': 'ACTG', 'b': 'ACCC', 'c': 'ACAT'}
{'a': 'ACCC', 'b': 'ACTG', 'c': 'ACAT'}
{'a': 'ACTG', 'b': 'ACAT', 'c': 'ACCC'}
{'a': 'ACAT', 'b': 'ACCC', 'c': 'ACTG'}
{'a': 'ACCC', 'b': 'ACTG', 'c': 'ACAT'}
{'a': 'ACCC', 'b': 'ACTG', 'c': 'ACAT'}
```

Comment: I suggest `dict(zip(...))`.

Comment: @timgeb thanks I don't have that reflex as I so use list/dict comprehension :D

Comment: Also I just realized calling `.keys()` is unnecessary, dicts are iterables of their keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop and [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) to shuffle the values of the `dict`, while changing the original `dict`.

Code:

```
import random

d = {"a": "ACAT", "b": "ACTG", "c": "ACCC"}

vals = list(d.values())
random.shuffle(vals)

for i, key in enumerate(d): d[key] = vals[i]
```

Explanation:

- `import random`, importing the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module
- `d = {"a": "ACAT", "b": "ACTG", "c": "ACCC"}`, setting `d` to a `dict`
- `vals = list(d.values())`, setting `val` to a list of all values of `d`
- `random.shuffle(vals)`, shuffling `vals`
- `for i, key in enumerate(d): d[key] = vals[i]`, changing `d` to the random values

Answer (score 0):

You can't really shuffle the values of the dictionary by simple writing:

```
shuffle(my_dict.values())
```

This will raise TypeError. But what you can do is to convert dictionary keys and values into a list, and then shuffle. Try the following code:

```
from random import shuffle

my_dict = {
    "a": "ACAT",
    "b": "ACTG",
    "c": "ACCC",
}

key_list = list(my_dict.keys())
values_list = list(my_dict.values())
shuffle(values_list)

for i in range(len(key_list)):
    my_dict[key_list[i]] = values_list[i]
```